# Playwright how to handle new windows

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

Im trying to login with steam on https://buff.163.com. My current code looks like this.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    page = browser.new_page()
    context = browser.new_context()
    page.goto("https://buff.163.com/market/csgo#tab=selling&page_num=1")
    page.locator("xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li/a").click()
    popup = page.wait_for_event("popup")
    page.get_by_text("Other login methods").click()
```

After it clicks the last button a new windows opens. How can i acces elements in there?

Comment: `popup = page.wait_for_event("popup")` seems unnecessary. Just proceed without it. The login dialog is a modal within the same page. `"xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li/a"` is easily broken and not good practice. I'd use a better locator, like text, role or class/id.

Comment: ok but how can i switch to the new window?

Comment: There's no need to "switch to the new window" because it's just a modal within the same page. So you don't need to do anything. There's an iframe wrapping part of the modal, so you may need to [select that](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-framelocator) if you plan to enter the mobile number and code at some point, but not the part you're asking about in this question.

Comment: Ah, I see--your script doesn't reproduce it for me, but after clicking `Other login methods` you do get the first popup.

Comment: You're also not using `context` so you might as well remove that, or use the context to generate the new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence seems to be a bit out of order. There's a modal after clicking the Login button, then a popup after clicking Other login methods. Try this flow:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright  # 1.37.0


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("<Your URL>")
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Login/Register").click()
    with page.expect_popup() as popup_info:
        page.get_by_text("Other login methods").click()
    popup = popup_info.value
    popup.wait_for_load_state()
    # interact with the popup...
    print(popup.title())
```